# not finishing activity when passing picture of byte array taken by camera

Tags: android

i am using a main activity which is calling a cameraActivity and using picture taken by camera. i am finish camera activity on pictureTaken and passing byte array to parent activity

```
  protected PictureCallback jpegCallback=new PictureCallback() {
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

               //Finishing Camera activity              
           Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
       bundle.putByteArray("imageToPreview", data);
       mPreview.imageBundle=bundle;
               Intent it=new Intent;
               it.putExtras(bundle);
               CameraActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,it);
       CameraActivity.this.finish();

        } 

      }
    };
```

so passing image byte array creating problem and result in not finish of activity.

if i pass simply

```
CameraActivity.this.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
CameraActivity.this.finish();
```

it working properly 
plz help i have to use this image in parent activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got the solution of my problem
actually we should not pass large amount of data through intent 
as mentioned [here](http://android.bigresource.com/Track/android-usuvgVYD8/)

Answer (score 1):

Hey sunil, same problem appeared wen i tried to work on image processing.
i was extracting image's pixels in bytearray and performing activity on array.
The problem was it was takin time to extract all bytes and so my program was becoming a big fussss.
But then i found in api that there were functions to stop performing next activity untill extraction is completed. also i was able to set max allowable time for extraction. check out in ur api such supportive methods and fields.